# How to set initial values of NSPopUpButton at startup in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I must be missing something obvious here.
I'm trying to load a few items in an NSPopUpButton when the app starts. I added the following code in the `init` method:

```
NSArray *listOfProfiles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"My Item 0", @"My Item 1", nil];
[profileListPopUp addItemsWithTitles:listOfProfiles];
NSLog(@"item 0 %@", [profileListPopUp itemTitleAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"item 1 %@", [profileListPopUp itemTitleAtIndex:1]);
```

And the output I get is:

```
2011-09-24 08:27:39.147 MyApp[3794:707] item 0 (null)
2011-09-24 08:27:39.148 MyApp[3794:707] item 1 (null)
```

However, if I put the code in another method that's called when pressing a different button, it works fine.
It seems that the `init` method is called before the NSPopUpButton is created but, in that case, I'd expect it to crash when referencing it.

Where should I put my code?

Bonus question: how do I get rid of the default values (other than calling `RemoveAll` on the control) that are loaded in the `NSPopUpButton`: 'Item 1', 'Item2' and 'Item 3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've not heard of the `-awakeFromNib` or `-windowDidLoadNib`methods, now would be a great time to read about them. My guess is your profileListPopUp pointer is at the time you're trying to add items to it because it's not been fully loaded from a nib yet.